# Webkit filter drop shadow removal

Tags: html, css, webkit

I'm having difficulty overriding (or simply removing) the `-webkit-filter drop-shadow` attribute placed on the text you can see in the image below. I need the drop-shadow on the speech bubble but not on the text below the bubble. I've tried setting the drop-shadow to white but that appears to have no effect. For positioning reasons I need to keep the text as a child element of the bubble. Can anyone tell me how I can achieve the desired effect, please?

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/zxE6F/).

**HTML**

```
<div class="bubble bubble-left">This is line 1 in speech bubble left.<br/> 
      This is line 2 in the bubble,<br/> and this is line 3.
      <div class="title">Title for bubble</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.bubble {
background-color: #fff;
-webkit-border-radius:7px;
-moz-border-radius:7px;
border-radius: 7px;
border: 3px solid #5E2750;
-webkit-filter: drop-shadow(4px 4px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.5));
-moz-filter: drop-shadow(4px 4px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.5));
-ms-filter: drop-shadow(4px 4px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.5)); 
-o-filter: drop-shadow(4px 4px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.5));
box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px hsla(0,0%,100%,.5), 4px 4px 0 hsla(0,0%,0%,.2);
color: #333;
font-family: Ubuntu, sans-serif;
font: 16px/25px;
padding: 15px 25px;
position: absolute;
}

.bubble:after, .bubble:before {
border-bottom: 25px solid transparent;
border-right: 25px solid #fff;
bottom: -25px;
content: '';
position: absolute;
right: 25px;
}
.bubble:before {
border-right: 25px solid hsla(0,0%,0%,.1);
bottom: -28px;
right: 22px;
z-index: 1;
}
.bubble:before {
border-right: 27px solid #5E2750;
border-bottom: 27px solid transparent;
bottom: -29px;
right: 23px;
z-index: 0;
}

.bubble-left {left: 25%;}
.bubble-right {right: 25%;}

.title {
/* remove drop-shadow/filter effect */
-webkit-filter: drop-shadow(4px 4px 5px rgba(255,255,255,1)) !important;
-moz-filter: none;
-ms-filter: none; 
-o-filter: none;
box-shadow: none;

color: #5E2750;
padding-left: 15px;
font-style:italic;
position: relative;
bottom: -43px;
left: 25%;
}
```

[image]

Comment: @Stefan V. that was my thinking too, but I was hoping to avoid that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your filter box shadow CSS properties to this format:

```
 -webkit-drop-shadow: (4px 4px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5));
 -moz-drop-shadow: (4px 4px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5));
 -ms-drop-shadow: (4px 4px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5));
 -o-drop-shadow: (4px 4px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5));
```

You might have to adjust your box shadow values to your liking:

Fiddle here: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zxE6F/30/)

Another way is to take out your Title for bubble link out of the bubble container and place the two in a new relative div. You will have to do some changes to your CSS though.

```
<div class="wrap">
        <div class="bubble bubble-left">This is line 1 in speech bubble left.
            <br/>This is line 2 in the bubble,
            <br/>and this is line 3.</div>
        <div class="title">Title for bubble</div>
    </div>
```

See fiddle: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zxE6F/12/)

Comment: [sorry, I managed by mistake to overwrite your earlier comment, Stefan]. That was my thinking too, but I was hoping to avoid that. I'm no CSS expert and have spent too much time on it so far, so would like to adapt what I have rather than starting afresh, so to speak.

Comment: Actually there might be another way. Try changing your filter box shadow properties this way: -webkit-box-shadow, -moz-box-shadow etc. See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zxE6F/20/

Comment: That's perfect, thanks Stefan! Can you edit your answer to include this and I will then accept it?